# How to Know current row number in MS access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Working lately on a program that displays specific info from database
according to the entered ID such that the ID equals to the current row in the db.

Code:

```
Dim y As Byte = Convert.ToByte(txtboxID.Text) - 1
lblname.Text = ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(1)
lblsub.Text = ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(2)
lblexp.Text = ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(3)
lblclass.Text = ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(4)
```

The problem here is when someone enters a new ID it won't match the row no. anymore. At first I thought that Access will add row automatically so that when ID 50 is entered there will be 50 rows, so anyone has a solution?

Comment: If you thought the auto incremented counter is the row number, then no, it's not, which is for many reasons, including the fact that [there is no order of rows in a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5779/5203). You should not attach any business logic to your primary keys. These numbers are designed to not mean anything.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advise .but how am i supposed to locate the  row that i'll get info from if i'm not gonna relay on IDs ? :D

Comment: You get its ID and you query the row with that ID from the table. You do not rely on number of rows before or after the row with that ID, and you do not use the ID number for anything other than querying that one single row.